# Unicode escape sequence for non-BMP plane character

Tags: java, unicode, encoding

In java,

Unicode characters can be represented using unicode escape sequence for  `UTF-16` encoding. Below is an example that represents BMP plane character

```
char ch = '\u00A5'; // '¥'
```

Can surrogate pairs be used for non-BMP plane characters?

```
char ch4 = '\uD800\uDC00'; //Invalid character constant
```

How do I represent non-BMP plane character using java syntax?

Comment: Remember that a Java `char` cannot hold a Unicode code point. It takes a Java `int` for that. That's because Unicode code points  go up to 0x10FFFF, but a Java `char` can only hold a value up to 0xFFFF.  A Java `char` is not a character.

Comment: @tchrist not a character?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do that with a single char constant, since a char is a UTF-16 code unit. You have to use a String constant, such as:

```
final String s = "\uXXXX\uYYYY";
```

where `XXXX` is the high surrogate and `YYYY` is the low surrogate.

Another solution is to use an `int` to store the code point; you can then use `Character.toChars()` to obtain a `char[]` out of it:

```
final int codePoint = 0x1f4ae; // for instance
final char[] toChars = Charater.toChars(codePoint);
```

Depending on what you use, you may also append code points directly (a `StringBuilder` has a method for that, for instance).

Comment: i get syntax error for `char ch4 = '\uD800\uDC00';`  error is: `Invalid character constant`

Comment: Of course you do; read my answer again: you can't use a char constant for that, you need a String constant

Comment: There's a typo in the code example: "Charater" instead of "Character". It can't be corrected with an edit because an edit must be at least six characters :-(

Answer (score 0):

To avoid writing surrogates pair for non-BMP chars and obtaining a String from a code point there are several methods.

```java
String test1 = new String(new int[] { 0x1f4ae }, 0, 1);
String test2 = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(0x1f4ae));
String test3 = Character.toString(0x1f4ae):
```